# Replace all values in list of lists according to positions in another list

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have a list, and a list of lists. I want to replace all values in each sub-list of the latter such that the value `i` is replaced by the value in the `i`-th position of the former. For example:

```
l = [4,2,1,0,3]
l_of_l = [[0,3],[4,1,2,3],[2,4]]

desired_output = [[4,0],[3,2,1,0],[1,3]]
```

All `0`'s are replaced by `l[0]`, which equals `4`. All `1`'s are replacd by `l[1]`, which equals `2`. And so on.

All the numbers appear just once in `l`, and all numbers between the maximum and the minimum are there. Namely, if the minimum value is `0` and the maximum is `6`, then the list will be a shuffled version of `list(range(7))`. Also, all numbers present in the lists that `l_of_l` contains are present in `l` (i.e. if the maximum value in `l` is `6`, there will not be any number greater than `6` in any list of `l_of_l`).

I've done this:

```
for this_l in l_of_l:
    for i in range(len(this_l)):
        this_l[i] = l[this_l[i]]
```

But I'm not very fond of loops. Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Do you need a fully recursive solution or is the structure always going to be a 2D list?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The structure will always be as the one in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
l = [4,2,1,0,3]
l_of_l = [[0,3],[4,1,2,3],[2,4]]
result = [[l[b] for b in i] for i in l_of_l]
```

Output:

```
[[4, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3]]
```

Or, if you wish to avoid explicit loops entirely, you can use `map`:

```
result = list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda c:l[c], x)), l_of_l))
```

Output:

```
[[4, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3]]
```

Although the latter is not nearly as clean as a list comprehension.

Comment: Please can you rename `l`. In may fonts this looks like `I`. Good not to encourage this convention :)

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is always an option, although it won't be in-place like your solution:

```
result = [[l[x] for x in row] for row in l_of_l]
```

I know you said you didn't want a fully recursive solution, but here is one that works for arbitrarily nested iterables containing integers and other iterables:

```
from functools import partial

def lookup(table, values):
    try:
        return list(map(partial(lookup, table), values))
    except TypeError:
        return table[values]
```

IDEOne Link: https://ideone.com/atwfnO

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid an explicit inner `for` loop by using `map` with `list.__getitem__`:

```
L = [4,2,1,0,3]
LoL = [[0,3],[4,1,2,3],[2,4]]

res = [list(map(L.__getitem__, i)) for i in LoL]

[[4, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [1, 3]]
```